# Using the command "sudo chrt -r 99" for a video encoding benchmark I always get bigger (worse) times

Tags: ubuntu, process, cpu, real-time, benchmark

I am using a video encoding benchmarking application. The strange thing to me is that when I am using the command `sudo chrt -r 99 VideoEncoding cfg` I always get bigger time (worse results) instead of using just `VideoEncoding cfg`. The difference between them is about 200 seconds for 150 frames which is huge. It is supposed that changing the real-time attributes of a process it will be faster, but instead, it proved to be slower.

Can someone explain this?

PS : I am running the benchmarks under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: This is a total misunderstanding of what real time semantics guarantee: you're always trading off latency, throughput, and the risk of priority inversions.

Comment: @ChrisDown Can you explain more on this? Smaller latencies better results, can RT properties achieve this? What about throughput and priority which as far as I remember is set to Round Robin?

Answer (score 3):

> It is supposed that changing the real-time attributes of a process it will be faster

**This is definitely wrong**.
Scheduling whatever under a real time policy might help achieving precise & deterministic latency, sync between tasks… but since there is no free lunch **to the expense of throughput**.

In the particular case of whatever cpu-bound task (what a video encoding task is) what you want is : **throughput** !

Therefore… scheduling that sort of task SCHED_RR will only kill the performances of everything on your system (this including… your benchmarking application).
And the more your cpu-bound task is multithreaded (likely with modern cpu-bound tasks), the more degraded perfs you will observe.

Renicing it should be just far enough to achieve better performances or, at the extreme limit, if highest possible performance needed then pin this task on some idle cpu.

**AND, BTW : Never never and never schedule anything RT with the max possible priority. If anything goes wrong, you'll never be able to do anything else but a hardware reset.**

Not to say BTW 2 : Benchmarking whatever RT system with whatever benchmarking application running under that same system is just : absurd.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So the SCHED_RR will kill performances., right?  The conclusion here is to avoid using ```chrt``` ? What else can I do to get stable performances for all my benchmarks? I used also to change the scaling_governor to performance like this ```echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor```. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: It doesn't "kill performance": it reduces throughput, but if your performance is measured in worst-case response time, it *rescues performance*. You need to think about how your transcoding system might have different notions of performance compared to an audio subsystem that needs to guarantee sound getting to and from applications in time, or a CNC control system that needs to emergency shutdown within 2 ms if something happens, or a cellular base station which needs to have responded to a control packet within 4ms, including generation of the RF signal.

Comment: (also, if there was one golden way to make your computer faster without downsides, then any serious operating system would do that, by default!)

Comment: @Maverick : When benchmarking whatever, do realize that A/ because initial conditions cannot be identical, benchmarks (even without changing anything in whatever configuration) will necessarily provide two different results. So you must always run your benchmark several time and consider the standard deviation. B/ because whatever benchmark (running on the same machine) will have to run at some time, it will pollute the result. => best is to get rid of the benchmark app and read the data you are interested in at a given moment of your workload and re-read that data at another moment.

Comment: @MC68020 I can not run my benchmark several times since they are very time-consuming and too many, consequently, I need weeks to finish only the 1st run. Since they are very time critical and they are using multithreading CPUs and GPUs, I want to benchmark minor updates to the source code and watch the final improvements. The problem here is that if I can not get reliable results to monitor the minor speedups then there is no way to improve the code. Under Windows which is the main developing system I can monitor the speedups but under Linux the whole project is falling down because of this.

Comment: Weeks to finish the 1st run ??? OMG !!! Change your benchmark apps is the best advice I have to offer. AND once again !!! DO NOT USE benchmark apps. Get the knowledge of the parameter you want to trace. Acquire the knowledge of the /proc directory tree (everything is gracefully kept there) and run YOUR workload watching (min max avg stdev) **that** data.

Answer (score 2):

> is supposed that changing the real-time attributes of a process it will be faster,

No. That's not true!

Making a process "real-time scheduled" doesn't make it faster, it just guarantees a maximum time between the process being scheduled. That leads to potentially more context switches, and hence effectively makes the system slower.

Comment: I am not sure… hmmm… I'm quite certain :-P that there should be no noticeable increase in context switches (because of task trheaded RR) an even less that context switches would, per se,  be responsible for eating 200/150 seconds cpu per frame processing.

Comment: But there should be. In non-rt processing, your encoding process runs until it context switches, or until an interrupt interrupts. On a multicore machine, that might simply mean the encoding process gets a full CPU core (or even multiple) for a looong time. RT scheduling is period-based, you're getting invoked at the end of each period (e.g., 10ms), but the OS rightfully assumes you're not going to work the whole period (otherwise, your real-time-ness makes no sense), so you get grouped on a CPU core with other short-running tasks.

Comment: What can I do to have a stable performance for my benchmarks? I used to change also the scaling_governor to performance.

Comment: yeah, that's about what you can do. Notice that you want high performance, not good-looking benchmarks, after all. (you're not trying to sell your hardware, you're trying to encode video, right.) So, maximize for throughput: performance scheduler, unburdened storage, enough RAM, and if you really want to experiment: using `sudo perf record`, you can observe how much time is spent where (incl. kernel resources), and if that seems promising, because you see a lot of process migrations between cores, as shown by

Comment: `sudo perf stat -d -d -e "sched:sched_process*,migrations,cs,cycles,task:*,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,faults" /path/to/your/executable` restrict potentially interfering processes to other CPU cores (`taskset`). And of course, as said in the other answer, just use `nice` to decrease niceness of your process!

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Your comment #1 : My point being that, **in that precise case** of chrting 99 a cpu-bound task, the task will never be scheduled out until it completes. Only raw level irq handlers (that would not even get followed by associated irq thread of a necessarily lower rt prio. => There would indeed **in that precise case** no additional context-switch.

Comment: @Maverick : "stable performance for your benchmark" ? what do you mean ? benchmarking is statistics. Do you mean you want to reduce some stdev ?

Comment: @MC68020 only if you assume no other RT tasks, which is unlikely on a modern Linux (pulseaudio/pipewire + potentially storage daemons); RT prio 99 doesn't guarantee never being interrupted, it only guarantees that you get scheduled once per period, even if that means other processes' demands don't get satisfied; `SCHED_RR` **limits** the runtime, even of p99 tasks! Now, how could that end up being *worse* in throughput than being "normally" scheduled? By being grouped with other processes on the same CPU core, thereby thrashing caches and forcing context switches.

Comment: @MC68020 With ```Stable``` performance,  I mean the conditions to run my benchmark to have almost the same results in every run, ie changing the governor from ```OnDemand``` to ```Performance```  mode I found also huge divergences at the runtimes that makes my benchmarks unreliable.

Comment: @Maverick I'm confused: do you care about *benchmarks* or about your actual *encoding speed*?

Comment: @Maverick : So you want to reduce the stdev ! What is the value of your starting point ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Marcus, the encoding speed is part of my benchmarks. As already mentioned if I leave the governor to "OnDemand" then in two consecutive runs with the same parameters I have encoding time divergences of about 150 secs which is problematic. If I change the governor to "Performance" then the results are acceptable. Trying to balance my system to get reliable results, I played also with the "chrt" command,  but I discovered that there are too many parameters to change to make my benchmarks reliable. Sure one of them is governor & as many others responded the "chrt" was a bad choice.

Comment: @MC68020 I am not if I understand your question. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Maverick what is the current standard deviation of your benchmarks? You can't say "I need to be better at a metric" without saying what your current metric's value is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My benchmark is computed automatically from the application itself in seconds at end of the encoding process.  The main problem here is that for the same YUV input video file and 150 frames, sequential runs return huge differences in the encoding time, in the end, ie 1st run 480 seconds, 2nd run 671 seconds and 3rd run 890 seconds. I can accept a tolerance of +-5% but the mentioned results are unacceptable.

Comment: if you want to say something like "95% of times I'm within 5% of the mean value", you will have to do a lot more than 3 runs. This is a statistics problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : For once on this one I wholeheartedly second you ! I think that OPs problem is more about benchmarking in general than about RT scheduling per se. (About what, between you & me… I will… keep standing on my position ! :-P ) ;-)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Reading once more the answers.... Question: Why the maximum guaranteed time scheduled for each process will potentially increase the context switching? What's best for a multi threading application? Maximum time for each thread ? I suppose yes cos you are saving time of the context switching (registers, program counter etc). So why this is bad?

Comment: You pinpointed the problem: each context switch costs massive amount of times and invalidates a lot of caches, effectively. So, the best option for a multithreaded application is using the non-realtime scheduler; that's it.